# Should i encrypt OpenId Claimer Identifier before storing it  in my database?

Tags: security, openid, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth in my ASP.NET website to implement login using other providers like google and yahoo. So for every user,i will get a Claimed Identifier from the provider ? Should i encrypt that before storing it into my database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Claimed Identifier isn't like a password.  It should be treated like you'd treat a username.

Whether or not you encrypt it is therefore based on your own privacy/security policies.